# Making changed to local bower dependencies

Tags: bower

We're using bower to manage all of our front-end dependencies for our project. I've run into an issue that I think is solvable, but I'm not familiar enough with bower to understand how to do it.

In our project we have one particular dependency that needs to be modified slightly, as in probably 3 lines of code, to meet out project needs. Obviously it's not kosher to edit the file in `bower_components` directly, but this change needs to be made. What's the best way to go about doing this, and maintaining the dependency tree without having to commit the `bower_components`.

Understandably we'd have to make a sort of "local copy" of the dependency that we grabbed from Github initially. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could fork it and point to your fork instead or just clone it somewhere locally and point to the local repo.